# Mean Value Theorem on Bessel Function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x^nJ_n (x))'=x^nJ_{n-1}(x)$ and $[x^{-n}J_n(x)]'=-x^{-n}J_{n+1}(x)$ equation such that $n,x>0.$ Show that $J_n(\alpha)=J_n(\beta)=0$ and $J_{n+1}(\gamma)=0.$

Hello! The Hint is show that can used the Mean Value Theorem about $J_n.$ By the form of the equation, I can suppose that $J_n$ is differentiable on $(\alpha,\beta)$ and continuous on $[\alpha,\beta]$, it follows that $\exists c\in (\alpha,\beta)$ such that $J_n(\beta)-J_n(\alpha)=J'_n(c)(\beta-\alpha).$ Now, can show that $J'(c)(\beta-\alpha)=0$ yes?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are asking for something like this:

Let be $0<\alpha<\beta$ with $J_n(\alpha) = J_n(\beta) = 0$. Then exists $\gamma\in(\alpha,\beta)$ s.t. $J_{n+1}(\gamma) = 0$.

Proof:

We define the auxiliary function $f(x) = x^{-n}J_n(x)$. By hypothesis,
$f(\alpha) = f(\beta)$. Applying the Rolle's theorem to $f$,
$$\exists\gamma\in(\alpha,\beta):\ f'(\gamma) = 0.$$
But $f'(\gamma) = -\gamma^{-n}J_{n+1}(\gamma)$ and this implies $J_{n+1}(\gamma) = 0$.